# Eclipse Maven Issue

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, websocket, glassfish

I have a maven websocket server project that i have on 2 computers with Eclipse Mars and both working well.
I got a new computer and installed jdk jre and eclipse, i got the same project and i when i run it i get this error:

```
INFO: Provider class loaded: org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.GrizzlyEngine
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/tyrus/core/ReflectionHelper
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.server.ServerContainerFactory.create(ServerContainerFactory.java:124)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.server.ServerContainerFactory.create(ServerContainerFactory.java:100)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.server.Server.start(Server.java:120)
    at Handlers.Main.runServer(Main.java:29)
    at Handlers.Main.main(Main.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.tyrus.core.ReflectionHelper
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
```

Print screen of my Maven jars:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw72_4dDmSOya0tCTThmVlhUcnM

Funny thing is a search on google tell me to add a library that i already brought with maven pom file, and i wouldn't be able to run it if i didn't have that library i will get compile errors.
so what i dont understand is:
1. I have the library in maven so why i get this error?
2. if i add the same library i already have it give me a new error.
3. why i have errors at all if the same project is working 100% on 2 other computers?

I think im missing something and im not sure what.
I have same jre installed but on the new computer i think the jdk is 1 version newer.
Thanks for the help.

P.S.
The library that is needed to add is the tyrus-core-1.1.jar